# In Linux, after installing the sdk, still it saying No such file or directory, how to fix it?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

I am trying to run and compile one application which needs to use the third party `sdk_linux32`.

But its missing the header file always even i did what mentioned in readme file. Any idea what am i missing?

```
/*Manual says this following should install the SDK without any problem so i did*/
$cd sdk_linux32
$sudo mkdir /usr/lib/sdk_linux32
$sudo cp -r build/bin/release/* /usr/lib/sdk_linux32
$sudo ldconfig /usr/lib/sdk_linux32     
$g++ main.cpp -lsdk_linux32 -o MyApp

main.cpp ... fatal error: sdk_linux/Core.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <sdk_linux/Core.h>
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you also copy the `include/*` to `/usr/include/sdk_linux32`?

Comment: I did but it says: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsdk_linux collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You don't need to put "how to fix it" in the question title. It's typically an implied part of your post! :-)

Comment: So it turned out you had to copy `build/bin/release/lib/*` not just `.../release/*` to get the lib file in `lib/sdk_linux32` and not in `lib/sdk_linux32/lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a guess - try below - you need to tell gcc where the header files are

```
g++ main.cpp -I/usr/lib/sdk_linux32
```

**EDITED**

And looking at your latest comment - you also need to tell the linker where the library is located

```
g++ main.cpp -I/usr/lib/sdk_linux32 -L/usr/lib/sdk_linux32/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the Core.h file actually located? (Hint: use "find /usr/lib/sdk_linux32 -type f -name Core.h" to find it.)

I'm guessing you didn't name your directory correctly in /usr/lib. You named it sdk_linux32, but the code seems to be looking for sdk_linux, but that's just a WAG ...